# Why am I getting no response from ajax data in codeigniter 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm doing search data without refreshing the page but I don't get any request responses. I tried editing my ajax code but nothing happens. I just started learning ajax yesterday so its new to me. Is it on my ajax code or is it on my controller? I even have my ajax link included.

Here is my view code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CRUD Practice</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            font-family: helvetica;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Search: <input type="text" name="search_text" placeholder="Enter your query" id="search_text"></h2>

    <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
    <a href="get_all">Get all data</a><br>
    <a href="get_id/(:num)">Get data by ID</a><br>
    <a href="add_view">Add data</a>
    <div id="result"></div>

<a href="<? echo base_url() ?>">Go Back</a>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            load_data();
            function load_data(query){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo  base_url()?>crud_controller/fetch",
                    method:"POST",
                    data : {query: query},
                    success: function(data){
                            $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
                var search = $(this).val();
                if(search != " "){
                        load_data(search);
                }else{
                        load_data();
                }
            })
        })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Crud_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Crud_model', 'crud');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('crud_view');
    }

     function fetch(){
        $this->load->model('Crud_model');
            $output='';
            $query='';
        if($this->input->post('query')){
                $query = $this->input->post('query');
        }

        $data = $this->Crud_model->fetch_data($query);

        $output .= '
        <table>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Created_at</th>
        ';

        if($data->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach ($data->result() as $row)
                {
                    $output .= '<tr>
                                                <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->description.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->created_at.'</td>
                                                <td>'.$row->updated_at.'</td>
                                            </tr>';
                }
        }else{
            $output .= '<tr><td> No Data Found </td></tr>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by adding some error handling to the `$.ajax`. You can also inspect the actual request(s) in your browser dev tools network tab to see if url is as expected, status of request, what is sent & received etc

Comment: You have included jQuery 2x, this is likely causing errors and probably stopping your AJAX from running at all.  All of this will be visible in your browser's devtools, you are working blind if you're not using them.

Answer (score 0):

I found some missing content in your code that I mention below.

1. You haven't created a proper HTML table.
2. You haven't parsed your data from the controller so you're not be getting any response.

So you first need to add the `json_encode` like this `echo json_encode($output);` at the end of the controller function.

Change your function be like this:

```
function fetch(){
    $this->load->model('Crud_model');
        $output='';
        $query='';
    if($this->input->post('query')){
        $query = $this->input->post('query');
    }

    $data = $this->Crud_model->fetch_data($query);

    $output .= '
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Created_at</th>
    <th>Updated_at</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ';

    if($data->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($data->result() as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->description.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->created_at.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->updated_at.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }else{
        $output .= '<tr><td> No Data Found </td></tr>';
    }

    $output .= '</tbody>';
    
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you have to display your $output variable.
without printing the variable ajax cant read the data from php.
For our reference:

```
  $output .= '
    <table>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Created_at</th>
    ';

    if($data->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($data->result() as $row)
            {
                $output .= '<tr>
                                            <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row->description.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row->created_at.'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row->updated_at.'</td>
                                        </tr>';
            }
    }else{
        $output .= '<tr><td> No Data Found </td></tr>';
    }
```

echo output;